# nodejs using pm2 and debug ，all the log output by the ‘debug’ module all to the stderr ,why?

Tags: node.js, debugging, logging, pm2

`pm2 -version:0.12.1;debug -version:2.1.0`

code:

```
 debug("Send data to client success! length " + buf.length+" Bytes!");
```

pm2 logs:

```
[1_control-15 (err)] Tue, 16 Dec 2014 12:36:50 GMT [1_control] Client.ts Send data to client success! length 100 Bytes!

[1_control-15 (err)] Tue, 16 Dec 2014 12:36:50 GMT [1_control]n Client.ts Send data to client success! length 135 Bytes!
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debug module from 2.* version is set all the log to the stderr,1.* version will be fine

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the question is still relevant, but as the [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) says, you can override this behavior like this:

```
  var debug = require('debug');
  var error = debug('app:error');

  // by default stderr is used 
  error('goes to stderr!');

  var log = debug('app:log');
  // set this namespace to log via console.log 
  log.log = console.log.bind(console); // don't forget to bind to console! 
  log('goes to stdout');
  error('still goes to stderr!');

  // set all output to go via console.info 
  // overrides all per-namespace log settings 
  debug.log = console.info.bind(console);
  error('now goes to stdout via console.info');
  log('still goes to stdout, but via console.info now');
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Set DEBUG_FD=1 can change output stream to process.stdout

```js
DEBUG_FD=1 node index.js
```

Comment: hmm I haven't been able to get this to work with `DEBUG_FD=1 DEBUG='quran' pm2 restart start.js`